# Image doesn't get saved, even though I get a confirmation

Tags: ios, if-statement, uiimagepickercontroller, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

**It works like this, so if someone having a similar problem, you can just do it like this**

So here is what I put in the applicationdidfinishlaunching

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"] == nil) { 
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

 }
```

Heres what I wrote in the

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSData *imageData;
UIImage *yourUIImage;
imageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourUIImage];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
yourUIImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serializing (archiving) an uninitialized variable. The variable `yourUIImage` is declared, but you never assign anything to it. Then you try to archive it. If you're lucky, `yourUIImage` simply is `nil`, but if you're unlucky it would crash due to the unitialized garbage pointer.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed myself. Thats why I added this snippet UIImage *yourUIImage = [yourUIImage valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; Thought that would do the trick, but it didnt.

Comment: Erm, meditate about that line for a second. You define `yourUIImage`, and you immediately read it again (`[yourUIImage valueForKey:]`) without it being set to something meaningful first.

Comment: Well tbh I just started with programming so I sometimes don't get the hang of it immediately when I did something wrong. I thought this is how I could assign it to the image that has to be saved. But I deleted it. I just have to figure out how I can assign it to the image, correct?

Comment: Yeah, what you really want to do is to implement the delegate method [imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) and there you query and save the image. At the point where you want it to do it now, the picker wasn't even shown on screen yet.

Comment: I edited it and did it according to the linked notes (thanks for that). He still doesnt seem to save the image ...

Comment: You're not saving the image to NSUserDefaults, you just set `yourUIImage.image`. You also need to serialize and save it to NSUserDefaults there.

Comment: Thank you sir, I did it and it finally works :) Now just to figure out how to compresse and resize the image but this is (_maybe_) a question for another day.

Answer (score 1):

It might sound stupid, but have you called `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` after setting your object?